# does play framework not support class to json or json to class mapping?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.3

I am newbie to play framework.

I had seen chapter 'JSON' in play framework documentation

It guide me to use case class, not normal class

so It seemed not to support json to class mapping

is it true?

"sorry for poor expression skill, I'm not a native"

Comment: Are you referring to the Scala version or the Java version? They use different JSON serialization tools by default (though you're free to use whatever library you like.)

Comment: @Mikesname 
I am referring scala version,

Answer (score 1):

What is exactly your problem ? Here is how it works in Java, it must be very close in Scala.
Let's say you have a class `MyClass` and and instance `myObject` of this class.

If you want to serialize :

```
JsonNode json =  play.libs.Json.toJson(myObject);
```

And if you want to deserialize :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
MyClass myObject = mapper.readValue(jsonNode.toString(), MyClass.class);
```

Obviously, you'll need to handle `JsonParseException`, `JsonMappingException`... to send a human readable message to your end user.